# How do I pass piped input to second command in an alias?

Tags: pipe, alias

I've defined an alias like:

```
alias xyz='command1; command2'
```

I want to pipe output of another command pqr to command2 like:

```
pqr | xyz -f -
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias is generally *not* good practice in non-interactive shell scripts ( [BashFAQ/080](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080) ). The way you have the alias defined in your OP, only the first commands reads from the standard input, because `;` terminates your standard input from going beyond your first command.

One possible way is to do a command grouping using `{..}`, so that any re-directions apply to the entire set of commands within the group. You can still retain your `alias` definition and do

```
alias xyz='{ command1; command2; }'
```

In which case your `comamnd1` unnecessarily gets a copy of the standard input. You can close it by doing

```
alias xyz='{ command1 < /dev/null ; command2 - ; }'
```

Or use functions to define your commands within.

```
xyz() {
    command1; command2
}
```

If your shell is `bash` or `zsh` that supports process substitution you can just define `command2` to receive stdin content as positional arguments. Re-define your function as

```
xyz() {
    command1
    command2 "$@"
}
```

and then call your command (`pqr`) as

```
xyz < <(pqr)
```

A simple demonstration of the above,

```
zoo() { date; sed 's/foo/boo/' "$@"; }
zoo < <(echo food)                     #(or) zoo <<<"food"
Mon Nov 25 02:44:49 EST 2019
bood
```

Comment: Your first couple of aliases would not wok with `pqr | xyz -f -` as the `-f -` would end up on the outside of the `{ ...; }` compound command.  Also, the `-` may not be a valid thing to give to `command2` (your second alias).  Your second function look ok, if you pass `/dev/null` into `command1`, but you would call it as `xyz -f -` to emulate what the user is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'll try the xargs approach, i.e.:

```
alias xyz='command1; command2 | xargs pqr'
```

That is equivalent for running `pqr` with `command2` as its input argument

Comment: The user want to pipe the output of `prq` into `command2 -f -`. They additionally don't want to make `prq` or `-f -` part of the alias.

Answer (score 0):

To pass something into the standard input of `command2` in the command list

```sh
command1; command2
```

you would have to make sure that `command1` does not read from standard input.  This could be done by redirecting the standard input from `/dev/null` into `command1`:

```sh
command1 </dev/null; command2
```

This leaves you with the alias

```
alias xyz='command1 </dev/null; command2`
```

which you would *not* be able to call with

```
pqr | xyz -f -
```

as that would be equivalent to

```
pqr | command1 </dev/null; command2 -f -
```

which is the same as

```
pqr | command1 </dev/null
command2 -f -
```

Instead, define `xyz` as a shell function:

```sh
xyz () {
    command1 </dev/null
    command2 "$@"
}
```

Here, `command2` would get both the standard input of the function as well as any command line arguments given to the function.

You would now be able to use this as in the pipeline `pqr | xyz -f -`.

If (and only if) the `-f -` arguments that you pass to `command2` is to say "read from standard input" (with `-` denoting standard input), then you could instead of `-` pass a process substitution to `xyz`, if your shell supports it:

```
xyz -f <(pqr)
```

With the above function, this would be the same as doing

```
command1 </dev/null
command2 -f <(pqr)
```